# Applying PCA before sending data to SVM

Tags: machine-learning

Before applying SVM on my data I want to reduce its dimension by PCA. Should I separate the *`Train data`* and *`Test data`* then apply PCA on each of them separately or apply PCA on both sets combined then separate them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually both provided answers are only partially right. The crucial part here is **what is the exact problem you are trying to solve**. There are two basic possible settings which can be considered, and both are valid under some assumptions.

#### Case 1

*You have some data (which you splitted to train and test) and in the future you will get more data coming from the same distribution*.

If this is the case, you should fit PCA on train data, then SVM on its projection, and for testing you just apply already fitted PCA followed by already fitted SVM, and you do exactly the same for new data that will come. This way your test error (under some "size assumptions" should approximate your expected error).

#### Case 2

*You have some data (which you splitted train and test) and in the future you will obtain a big chunk of unlabeled data and you will be able to fit your model **then**.*

In such a case, you fit PCA on whole data provided, learn SVM on labeled part (train set) and evaluate on test set. This way, once new data arrives you can fit PCA using both your data and new ones, and then - train SVM on your old data (as this is the only one having labels). Under the assumption that again - data comes from the same distributions, everything is correct here. You use more data to fit PCA only to have a better estimator (maybe your data is really high dimensional and PCA fails with small sample?).

Answer (score 0):

You should do them separately. If you run pca on both sets combined then you are going to introduce a bias in your svn. The goal of the test set is to see how your algorithm will perform without prior knowledge of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the Projection Matrix of PCA on the train set and use this to reduce the dimensions of the test data.

One benifit is this way you don't have to rely on collecting sufficient data in the test set if you are applying your classifier for actual run time where test data comes one sample at a time.

Also I think separate train and test PCA will fail.Why?

Think of PCA as giving you features, and then you learn a classifier over these features. If over time your data shifts, then the test features you get using PCA would be different, and you don't have a classifier trained on these features. Even if the set of directions/features of the PCA remain same but their order varies your classifier still fails.